# Why i can't move image and set text in label at the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint

I want to move background to the left like my character is walking and show number of walking  but it can't do that at the same time. this method leftfootButton can only set text in label

```
- (IBAction)leftfootButton:(id)sender {
    _bgGround.center = CGPointMake(_bgGround.center.x -50, _bgGround.center.y);
    i = i+1;
    self.show.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
}
```

If i comment the code that sets the text out then it can move background

```
- (IBAction)rightfootButton:(id)sender {
    _bgGround.center = CGPointMake(_bgGround.center.x - 50, _bgGround.center.y);
    i = i+1;
    //self.show.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
}
```

what should i do?

Comment: Do you use auto layout?

Comment: yes i use auto layout

Comment: You should not change frames directly when you use auto layout because `layoutSubviews` method will return frames to their previous position.

Comment: Also, you are setting constant frame to your `_bgGround`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change frames directly when you use auto layout because [layoutSubviews](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) method will return frames to their previous position. This method is called by system in many cases. You could override it to set the frame rectangles of your subviews directly. But I recommend you to change constraints of your background view. Even if you did not set constraints to your views, they was added automatically.

Comment: i create new project with out auto layout it still not working

Comment: Try this: turn on auto layout, add a leading constraint to your view, make an outlet for this constraint and decrease its constant's value to move your view to the left.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Layout Constraint then you should never change the frame, you should try to change the constraint, e.g.

Create a IBOutlet for x contraint for the view like below, make sure it's correctly connected.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *xContraint;
```

Then in your action

```
- (IBAction)leftfootButton:(id)sender {
  self.xContraint.constant -= 50;
  i = i + 1;
  self.show.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
}
```